# Selected from a typed set

Tags: oracle10g

How can I select from a typed set in Oracle 10g?

I.E. `SELECT * FROM (3,5,20,68,54,13,56,899,1)`

Additionally, how would I filter it?

I.E. `SELECT * FROM (3,5,20,68,54,13,56,899,1) WHERE > 5`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where is the data coming from and what are you planning on doing with it?

If the data is being read from a file, you would normally create an external table to read from the file or use SQL*Loader or some other ETL tool to load the data into a staging table or a PL/SQL collection that you could then query

```
SQL> create type num_tbl is table of number;
  2  /

Type created.

SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  declare
  2    l_nums num_tbl := num_tbl( 3, 5, 20, 68, 54 );
  3  begin
  4    for x in (select * from table(l_nums))
  5    loop
  6      dbms_output.put_line( x.column_value );
  7    end loop;
  8* end;
SQL> /
3
5
20
68
54
```

If you're doing some sort of manual process, you would normally be looking for data from another table, i.e.

```
SELECT *
  FROM some_other_table
 WHERE some_key IN (3, 5, 20, 68, 54, 13, 56, 889, 1 );
```

If you're really trying to generate a data set full of arbitrary data pulled from a file that you don't want to use Oracle to read, you can always do a series of `SELECT` statements from `DUAL` that are all `UNION ALL`'d together but this obviously gets rather cumbersome.

```
WITH sample_data
  AS (SELECT 3 num FROM dual UNION ALL
      SELECT 5 FROM dual UNION ALL
      SELECT 20 FROM dual UNION ALL
      SELECT 68 FROM dual UNION ALL
      SELECT 54 FROM dual UNION ALL
      ...
      SELECT 1 FROM dual)
 SELECT *
   FROM sample_data
  WHERE num > 5;
```

Additionally, using the WITH clause and a CSV string we can parse a string as a table.
Example:

```
VARIABLE liste VARCHAR2(100)

EXECUTE :liste := '5, 25, 41, 52'; 

WITH liste AS (
  SELECT SUBSTR(:liste, INSTR(','||:liste||',', ',', 1, rn),
  INSTR(','||:liste||',', ',', 1, rn+1) - 
  INSTR(','||:liste||',', ',', 1, rn)-1) valeur
FROM (
  SELECT ROWNUM rn FROM DUAL
  CONNECT BY LEVEL<=LENGTH(:liste) - LENGTH(REPLACE(:liste,',',''))+1))
SELECT TRIM(valeur)
FROM liste;
```

Comment: 1-10 is just a random sample I provided, real usage will be very very different and not in a predictable pattern. It's around 900 9 digit numbers. The numbers are being copy and pasted in from data pulled out of a log file.

Comment: @Malfist - I updated my answer to discuss your options if you're not trying to programmatically generate the data.

Comment: What's happened is there's been a a bunch of commit errors so I have a bunch of what should be primary key ids that I need to verify aren't actually in the database. So the second suggestion won't work.

Comment: I'm going to edit your answer and put what I actually found to work. Your WTIH and DAUL put me on the right track, but I found a cleaner solution.